# Android: Start Service with Context.startService vs PendingIntent.getService

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context, android-pendingintent

**Context.startService**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
context.startService(intent);
```

**PendingIntent.getService**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
pi.send();
```

**Questions**

1. When would you start a service with Context.startService vs a PendingIntent?
2. Why would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There really is no difference.

Specifically the Context method is used to directly start it where as a PendingIntent is typically used with a notification to fire this intent when it is tapped, which is delayed until the user taps it (typically). However; you wouldn't typically send the PendingIntent directly because that is not what it is for.

A PendingIntent is an Intent that is pending, pending, meaning that its **NOT** supposed to happen now, but in the near future. Whereas with an Intent, it is sent at the very moment.

If a PendingIntent is not pending when it is used, then it is no longer a PendingIntent and it is infact an Intent. **Defeating the purpose entirely**.

Comment: So, is there ever a time when you would want to start a service with a `PendingIntent`?

Comment: If you want to start a service in the near future, this would be the ideal case. Say I have a notification that displays new update available for a user's account. Ideally there would be a pending intent that would establish a connect to a server and download this information. I want it done when the user has tapped the notification NOT immediately, this way I wait for the user's convenience, or if the user doesn't care they can cancel the notification and the next new update will react the same way.

Answer (score 1):

PendinIntents are very much used for widgets. As the layout of a running widget doesn't "belong" to your code, but it is instead under control of the system, you can't assign directly click listeners to the interface elements. Instead you assign a PendingIntent to those elements (like buttons) so when the user touches them, the PendingIntent is "executed", something like:

```
// get the widget layout
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.id.widget_layout);

// prepare to listen the clicks on the refresh button
Intent active = new Intent(context, WidgetCode.UpdateService.class);
PendingIntent refreshPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, active, 0);
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonWidgetRefresh, refreshPendingIntent);

// send the changes to the widget
AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(appwidgetid, remoteViews);
```

In this case a button in the widget starts a service. Usually you put extra info in the intent, with putExtras(), so the service will get any needed information to do its job.

Comment: Just notice that you have to add your service in manifest
and add export="true" property its important